# NoClassDefFoundError executing jar using jaxrpc

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have developed a Webservice client application using jaxrpc. Within eclipse the application runs fine, however after I have exported the jar file, I get the following runtime error

```
D:\>java -jar Myclient2.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/rpc/Service
Exception
        at Mynet.MyScheduler.<init>(MyScheduler.java:47)
        at Mynet.MyScheduler.<init>(MyScheduler.java:36)
        at Mynet.MyNetMain.main(MyNetMain.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

I have tried to set the CLASSPATH variable but no changes.

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:\eclipse\plugins\javax.xml.rpc_1.1.0.v201209140446\lib\jaxrpc.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.axis_1.4.0.v201005080400\lib\axis.jar

echo %CLASSPATH%
java -jar Myclient2.jar
```

I am rather new to java so definitely a newbie question
KR

Answer (score 0):

You should consider migrating your web service to JAX-WS. JAX-RPC is an older java web service technology that is unlikely to be maintained much moving forward.

But the single biggest benefit you will experience is that all of the JAX-WS runtime and tooling has been part of the Java JDK since Java 6. This means that you can build web services with no runtime library dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had trouble to find the JAX-WS support in Eclipse, so I have followed a tutorial using AXIS.
However, I still don`t know how I could get it run without porting to JAX-WS.

Comment: Yes, I am using Kepler

Comment: Are you starting from a WSDL or from java classes?

Comment: Yes, I would like to write a client to an existing web service which provides a WSDL.

Comment: When I use wsimport -keep my.wsdl the generation of the stub files fail with the following error
[ERROR] "Use of SOAP Encoding is not supported
SOAP extension element on line 37 in file:/D:/...

Comment: Modern web services no longer support SOAP encoding as it is not portable. You need to change this in your wsdl. Another good reason to leave Axis in the past. Google for more info

Answer (score 0):

Anytime that you get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"; it is very probable that you are missing a jar file.
you should search for the jar file containing "javax/xml/rpc" and then add it to your classpath or as a dependency to your maven project.
Here you should find them:

http://search.maven.org/

http://mvnrepository.com/